# LinearModelFit returns a large error for x^2

Tags: fitting

I have the following list of {x,y} measurements:

```
data = {{-786,57165.85142}, {-785,57166.82179}, {-783,57168.7566}, {-754,57196.8592}, {-752,57198.79802}, {-721,57228.8369}, {-711,57238.5279}, {-618,57328.6444}, {-617,57329.61146}, {-616,57330.58151}, {-582,57363.52676}, {-220,57714.30206}, {-13,57914.88456}, {-12,57915.8537}, {-3,57924.5724459714}, {-2,57925.5431454405}, {-1,57926.5126174843}, {0,57927.4807292757}, {0,57927.48156}, {1,57928.4484975385}, {3,57930.3884705215}, {19,57945.8913080529}, {20,57946.8611116146}, {31,57957.5198907501}, {32,57958.48844}, {33,57959.4585221843}, {34,57960.427616946}, {36,57962.3654357807}, {61,57986.5897409271}, {63,57988.5283625425}, {63,57988.52797}, {64,57989.4970048797}, {97,58021.4728487521}, {97,58021.47346}, {98,58022.4417642814}, {98,58022.44219}, {99,58023.4109042856}, {102,58026.31752}, {133,58056.3570380043}, {386,58301.512797252}, {387,58302.4819962335}, {388,58303.4493962563}, {420,58334.45858}, {452,58365.46578}, {455,58368.37232}, {489,58401.31876}, {774,58677.4807795334}, {808,58710.4293663136}, {809, 58711.3956061853}, {811,58713.3346100197}, {812,58714.30249946}, {813,58715.2738916154}, {814,58716.2409417503}, {815,58717.2104497994}, {817,58719.1478213525}, {824,58725.9320213815}, {825,58726.9007608371}, {826,58727.8688212844}, {827,58728.8382266304}, {828,58729.8065785796}, {829,58730.7763825156}, {830,58731.7452825247}, {831,58732.7152532531}, {832,58733.6833612458}, {842,58743.372444021}, {843,58744.3407326168}, {1097,58990.4655949678}, {1159,59050.5447233861}, {1332,59218.1795938651}};
```

The known uncertainty of the y measurements are:

```
errors = {0.00099,0.000865,0.00185,0.00275,0.00072,0.001,0.00175,0.0013,0.000925,0.000455,0.000909,0.000705,0.00051,0.00062,0.0004333651,0.0003381485,0.0002382498,0.0002284928,0.00047,0.0019850483,0.0004945073,0.001058397,0.000687089,0.000299267,0.00026,0.0005136467,0.0003561497,0.0010452804,0.0003407055,0.0004464173,0.000385,0.0005289212,0.0005933795,0.000385,0.000627954,0.00046,0.0006943395,0.00071,0.0004377928,0.000296358,0.0002621614,0.0005375192,0.00061,0.00063,0.000475,0.000275,0.0007060317,0.0012267862,0.0007148853,0.000492908,0.0006186566,0.0008285629,0.0005951712,0.0005261253,0.0009616619,0.0007392007,0.0007552545,0.0006087647,0.0005442889,0.0008865575,0.0006663125,0.0008987173,0.0006109868,0.0007710725,0.000897824,0.0005552567,0.00084034,0.0002589853, 0.0007958238};
```

I performed a quadratic fit:

```
lmq = LinearModelFit[data, {x, x^2}, x, Weights -> errors]

lmq["ParameterTable"]

lmq["BestFitParameters"]

lmq["ParameterErrors"]
```

The quadratic fit returns a large error for x^2.
Estimate = -3.98794*10^-10
Standard Error = 3.36075*10^-10

It is only 1.2 sigma result and is not significant. I used another fitting code and I obtained a lower error for x^2.
Where am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Try to compare with `Weights -> 1/errors^2`, also see related questions.

Comment: From plotting the data it is very clear that the linear term dominates and I don't understand why you're surprised that the quadratic term is not significant (even using the more appropriate weight that @I.M. suggested).  Maybe the other "fitting code" is wrong.  Showing that other code would be helpful to pin down the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @I.M. Using Weights -> 1/errors^2 ì, I obtain the same values that I get from the other code.